# Pegar informações, abrir janela e só liberar a janela quando colocar uma senha. Python

Tags: python

Vou simular um ataque na minha empresa para identificar os usuários mais vulneráveis para intensificar o treinamento com objetivo de evitar ransomware e virus do tipo.
Estou tentando criar um programinha .exe que pegue as informações do computador (nome da maquina, nome do usuário, sistema operacional e a data atual) e enviar por email. Após isso, queria que abrisse uma janela com algumas mensagens repetitivas para impossibilitar o usuario continuar trabalhando e que só libere com uma senha que o T.I tenha. Podem me auxiliar?

Meu código atual está assim:

```
import platform
from datetime import datetime
import getpass
import ctypes

so = platform.system()

print ("Sistema Operacional:"+so)
print ("Nome da máquina:"+platform.node())
print ("Nome do usuário:"+getpass.getuser())


data_e_hora_atuais = datetime.now()
data_e_hora_em_texto = data_e_hora_atuais.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

print(data_e_hora_em_texto)


def Mbox(title, text, style):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)
Mbox('ATENÇÃO!!!!@@!!', 'VOCÊ BAIXOU O ARQUIVO, CERTO?', 3)
Mbox('ATENÇÃO!!!!@@!!', 'VOCÊ FOI INFECTADO :)', 0)
Mbox('ATENÇÃO!!!!@@!!', 'NÃO TENTE FAZER NADA SENÃO VAMOS ESPALHAR POR TODA REDE', 0)
Mbox('ATENÇÃO!!!!@@!!', 'CHAME ALGUÉM DO T.I PARA CONVERSAR COMIGO', 0)

n = 1

while n != 0:
    n = int(input('Digite a senha: '))
print('Liberado')
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários. Veja [ask] e faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score -3):

Tente isto:
Primeiro verifica se `n != 0` e não é `123456`:

Obs: A senha do T.I você poderia colocar em um arquivo de variáveis de desenvolvimento ou algo do tipo...

```
n = 1

while n != 0 and n != 123456:
    n = int(input('Digite a senha: '))

    if n == 123456:
        print('Liberado')
    else:
        print('Senha incorreta')
```

**123456** você pode mudar pra senha que escolher

Comment: Ata, entendi o que vc quer, vc quer bloquear o computador do cara realmente... acho que não vamos poder te ajudar com isso... mas está aí um trecho do código...